# 3D Latex Text in react-three/fiber

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I am trying to write a few math equations in 3D with `react-three/fiber`, and have been looking for a way to get it working with latex.

Currently I have been using the `Text3D` component in `@react-three/drei`, have been googling and looking for ways to allow latex, though no luck.

I'm guessing I will be able to do it if I write an equation, export the SVG, then make it into a 3D object. Though it would be nice, if there was a faster way.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Try this npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/mathmesh

works for both babylon and three

its not perfect but its something.

Example to use in three js with react fiber:

```
import {mathmesh} from "mathmesh";
const vertices = mathmesh("\\int_{a}^{b}x^2 \\,dx").vertices;
...
<bufferGeometry >
  <bufferAttribute
        attach='attributes-position'
        array={vertices}
        count={vertices.length / 3}
        itemSize={3}
    /> 
</bufferGeometry>
```

[image]